# RubyMine: List all methods that are called in a file?

Tags: ruby, rubymine

I want to get a list of all methods that are called in a given file. For clarification, I am not referring to the more common task of finding all usages for a ***specific*** method. Instead, I want to collect all unique names of ***any*** method that is explicitly called by name within a file. I know RubyMine can detect whether an entity in a file's code is a method call, so is there any way for RubyMine to give me a list of all methods called in a file?

Comment: You simply cannot know what methods *will* or *could* be called without running the code through *all possible paths* with *all possible inputs*. Static code analysis can reveal the most obvious calls, but not always. Ruby is, like many highly dynamic languages, extremely difficult to predict. You must collect data from actual usage.

Comment: For what it's worth, tools like [Sorbet](https://sorbet.org), which is like TypeScript for Ruby, aims to try and constrain Ruby so it is a lot more predictable. Maybe that's a step towards your goal.

Comment: @tadman: It's not just Ruby, by the way. Figuring out which method gets called is, in the general case, provably equivalent to solving the Halting Problem even in languages like Java, C#, and C++. It is a well-known problem since de-virtualization is a common optimization in C++ compilers, but this limitation means that it cannot be guaranteed. That's why things like Polymorphic Inline Caching exist in JIT compilers. It's one of the reasons JIT compilers can outperform AOT compilers for OO languages.

Comment: _"methods that are called in a file"_ leaves some room for interpretation. Do you mean called from that very file or also from other files? Are you interested in methods that were actually called during a specific session (runtime analysis) or those that could theoretically be called based on all possible code paths (static analysis)? Maybe it would help to know _why_ you want this list? Are you trying to detect unused code?

Comment: @Stefan I am trying to find method calls that are explicitly written into the code text of a given file, so nothing having to do with runtime. Mostly, this is a parsing problem that I am trying to find a solution for. I've found that RubyMine does a great job of distinguishing whether an entity in a file is a variable name vs. a method call, so I was wondering if I could utilize this detection feature to somehow compile a list of all the explicitly written method calls it can find in my files.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to find method calls that are explicitly written into the code text of a given file, so nothing having to do with runtime

Let's say we have this example file: (the code doesn't make any sense but its syntax is valid)

```
# test.rb           # 1
class MyClass       # 2
  def my_method     # 3
    foo             # 4
    self.bar        # 5
    baz(1)          # 6
    1 + 2           # 7
  end               # 8
end                 # 9
```

For static code analysis, you could use Ruby's [`AbstractSyntaxTree`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/RubyVM/AbstractSyntaxTree.html):

```
ast = RubyVM::AbstractSyntaxTree.parse_file('test.rb')
#=> #<RubyVM::AbstractSyntaxTree::Node:SCOPE@1:0-8:22>
```

The returned [`Node`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/RubyVM/AbstractSyntaxTree/Node.html) has a `children` method which can be used to traverse the syntax tree. The root node is of type `SCOPE` which represents a lexical scope.

The node types you are looking for are probably:

- `VCALL` – a method call without receiver or arguments
- `CALL` – a method call with explicit receiver
- `FCALL` – a method call with arguments
- `OPCALL` – method call using an operator

Here's a very simplistic parser:

```
def each_call(node, &block)
  return unless node.is_a?(RubyVM::AbstractSyntaxTree::Node)

  case node.type
  when :VCALL, :FCALL
    block.call(node.type, node.children[0], node.first_lineno)
  when :CALL, :OPCALL
    block.call(node.type, node.children[1], node.first_lineno)
  end

  node.children.each { |child_node| each_call(child_node, &block) }
end
```

Usage:

```
each_call(ast) do |type, name, lineno|
  puts "#{type}: `#{name}' on line #{lineno}"
end
```

Output:

```
VCALL: `foo' on line 4
CALL: `bar' on line 5
FCALL: `baz' on line 6
OPCALL: `+' on line 7
```

This should get you started in writing your own method call extractor.

Comment: This is a great guide, thank you! I opted to use a different syntax tree gem `syntax_tree`, but essentially my methodology was the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do it in RubyMine. One of the options is to use the [parse tree](https://github.com/seattlerb/parsetree) and get the list of all methods there.